# Unity 2019.4.11f1: PlayerPrefs not being saved on Android Device but saving correctly in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using PlayerPrefs to save 5 highscores in our game. The PlayerPrefs work fine when using the Unity editor but when I build and run the game on my Android, the scores do not save.

--Update--

When hard coding (Setting the Value Manually) the high scores, the values show up on Android. However, the scores do not get compared to the score the player has when he loses.

```
    void Update() {
    if (CurrentHealth == 0)
    {
        Dead();
    }
}

void Dead() {
    pauseMenuUI.SetActive(true);
    Time.timeScale = 0f;

    //Check to see if a high score is achieved
    scoreManager.checkScore(score.returnScore());
    
}
```

**Code to check for highscores and save to PlayerPrefs**

```
    public void checkScore(int score)
{

    if(score > PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore1" ))
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HighScore1", score);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();

    }

    else if (score > PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore2"))
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HighScore2", score);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();

    }

    else if (score > PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore3"))
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HighScore3", score);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();

    }

    else if (score > PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore4"))
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HighScore4", score);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();

    }

    else if (score > PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore5"))
    {
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HighScore5", score);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();

    }

}
```

**Code the retrieves high scores from PlayerPrefs**

```
    private void Awake()
{
    instance = this;
    
            highScore1 = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore1");
            highScore2 = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore2");
            highScore3 = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore3");
            highScore4 = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore4");
            highScore5 = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore5");
    
    createArray();
}

void Start()
{
    
}

//Creates Initial Array
public void createArray()
{
    int[] HighScore = {highScore1, highScore2, highScore3, highScore4, highScore5};
    this.HighScore = HighScore;
}

//Allows for the array to be returned
public int[] getArray()
{
    createArray();
    
    return this.HighScore;

}
```

**Code that prints Highscores to Screen**

```
    public String[] printScores() // Gett array of high scores as string array
{
    Highscores = scoreManager.getArray(); 
    String[] scores = new string[Highscores.Length];
    for(int i = 0; i < Highscores.Length; i++)
    {
        text.text = text.text +  "Score " + (i+1).ToString() + "                                          " + Highscores[i].ToString() + "\n";
    }

    return scores;
}
```

I am building and running the game on a Galaxy S10+. The code to check for a high score is called when the player loses. The code to print the scores is called in the Start() method of that scene.

Comment: Check if the file get's saved on your phone you can find the locations for the files in the Unity Documentation https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html

Comment: If it doesn't work at all (Folder doesn't exist) you would probably need to writer your own safe method and file into the Application.persistantPath. Is probably better for High scores anyway because you can encrypt and decrpyt your file so that manipulation becomes much harder.

Comment: What MathewHD suggests it at least way saver in regards to user progress loss. You should rather save important values into a dedicated file

Comment: @MathewHD After testing some more things out, I believe it could possibly be an issue with the method comparing the scores which is in another file. When I hard code values in the script with the PlayerPref code, it shows up on Android.

Answer (score 0):

**Keep an eye on PlayerPrefs! They like to change.**

Jokes apart, the difference between your computer and your phone with PlayerPrefs is just about the first value. If you call a PlayerPrefs.GetInt the first time, the value will be random, it won't start from zero. On your computer, you were probably be able to SetInt the Highscore the first time and so in the next attempts, it always worked.
On the phone, when you first played the game, the first high score maybe was negative and so all the rest of your system broke!

Instead of writing

```
PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Higscore");
```

Write

```
PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Higschore",0);
```

In this way, if Unity doesn't found the value the first time it will set it to zero. And your system will work fine

Comment: `the value will be random, it won't start from zero` .. never heard of that .. if the key does not exist it will use the default value for `int` which is `0` ...

Comment: @derHugo ok maybe it's not random, but it's not even zero. Maybe it depends on the device, but I think that player prefs will search from a memory cell that doesn't exist like if you search for the 7th cell of an array of dimension 6. When I was coding for android, I had a default high score of a number with 6 digits and the maximum value on my game was like 2 digits long.  I think that this is also why PlayerPrefs have this section for default value. But maybe I'm wrong :D

Comment: if you checkout the [source code e.g. here](https://github.com/jamesjlinden/unity-decompiled/blob/master/UnityEngine/UnityEngine/PlayerPrefs.cs) you will find `public static int GetInt(string key)
    {
      int defaultValue = 0;
      return PlayerPrefs.GetInt(key, defaultValue);
    }` for the version without the default parameter ;)

Comment: This can remain between you and me mister @derHugo ;)

Comment: @Leoverload Sorry for the late response. Changing the GetInt() to include the default value did not solve the problem. However  I have been testing some things, and hard coding the values has made the values pop up on Android.         if(PlayerPrefs.HasKey("HighScore1"))
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HighScore1", 15);
        }